# AngularJS typeahead and html in results

Tags: angularjs

I have one view that has this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="accountNumber" ng-model="controller.order.accountNumber" typeahead-on-select="controller.onSelect($item)" typeahead="item.title + '<br />' + item.value + '<br />' + item.detail for item in controller.autoComplete($viewValue)" />
```

I have tried to add some formatting into the result set that is returned.
This actually works fine on this view (dispite visual studio moaning about quotation marks).

On another view, I have this set up:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="sku" ng-model="controller.orderLine.sku" typeahead-on-select="controller.onSelect($item)" typeahead="item.value + '<br />' + item.title + '<br />' +  item.detail for item in controller.autoComplete($viewValue)" />
```

On this view, the **break** is shown as text.

I don't suppose anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a default template:

```
<a href tabindex="-1">
    <div ng-if="match.model.title"><h4>{{ match.model.title }}</h4></div>
    <div ng-if="match.model.value">{{ match.model.value }}</div>
    <div ng-if="match.model.value">{{ match.model.detail }}</div>
</a>
```

My typeahead html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <form name="searchForm" role="form">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="controller.selected" typeahead-on-select="controller.onSelect()" typeahead-template-url="template/typeahead/typeahead-account-match.html" typeahead="item.accountNumber as item for item in controller.autoComplete($viewValue)" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**note:** You can see that I am setting the **typeahead-template-url** to the template above. If your templates are not likely to change, then you can omit that attribute and just override **template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html** and it will use that.

I hope this helps someone else :)